Why is Coraje used after a noun here?
A headline from El País grabbed  my attention. I can't seem to find the link but it was from 17/04/2024. It was entitled: Dos mujeres coraje
Subsequently, I found an article about the same women with a different title.
My question is, why is coraje, meaning courage, expressed like this after the nouns? Why isn't it dos mujeres de coraje?
I checked online and coraje seems to be borrowed from french albeit many centuries ago.
Perhaps, this is why it comes after the noun and does not have a preposition (de) in between?
I know valiente and bravo exist.
I asked a question months ago along these lines but slightly different.
The RAE also states with a word like clave that it seems to describe a fundamental element of it

clave
7. f. Elemento básico, fundamental o decisivo de algo. Su intervención fue la clave del éxito. U. t. en apos. Fechas clave. Tema clave.
Sin.:  esencia, quid, secreto, llave, fórmula.

So, is it something that makes it stand out or defines its' essence?
Although,I use these expressions I don't understand why they are the way they are .

You may have witnessed an error or you could be misremembering what you saw, but "dos mujeres coraje" sounds wrong in Spanish and it this form is not used anywhere I know of.  If you can't find the headline anymore it may be because the news site corrected the wrong headline.

@jachguate I see what you mean  but I searched now and I see other sites with this sort of title e.g. https://www.infobae.com/america/peru/2022/03/08/dia-de-la-mujer-8m-mujeres-coraje-pasaron-por-duros-momentos-pero-lograron-superar-ese-trance-para-luchar-por-ellas-y-sus-familias/

@Megustalafruta Es interesante. Y qué le parece a mi pregunta  y lo de la gramática? Como explica usted ese tipo de norma?

I don't get why you mentioned the word "clave". What's its relation with "coraje" or "mujeres coraje"? I also see not point in the quora post. As I pointed in my answer there's an adjective related with coraje: corajudo. The word mentioned in that quora post, "corajoso" in not used (labeled as des(usado) in the DRAE).

I think that it has been already mentioned here. What you found it's know as aposición, basically two nouns together. Coraje is not an adjective. The directly derived adjective is corajudo, pretty used in México, at least according to some films and tv series.
According to Fundeu

en este tipo de expresiones solo el primer sustantivo suele llevar la marca de plural, quedando el segundo, que modifica, matiza o complementa al primero, invariable en cuanto al número.

which in English can be summarize: the plural usually goes in the first name. That's the reason for not having mujeres corajes.
You can find some other examples in the link, like hombres rana, carriles bici, ciudades dormitorio ...
In Spain, we have also a person known as padre coraje.

ok. It is a double noun situation. I dodn't know such a thing existed grammatically. I suppose it is the same as in English when we say   ,commuter towns,bus lanes,guide dogs.I never thought of it that way. I mentioned Clave as I thought it was the same idea as Coraje.Am I wrong?

@Bluelion7 You're right. I missed "U.t  en apos." there. "Utilizado también en aposición".

That's just a reference to Bertolt Brecht's play Madre Coraje y sus hijos (in English: ''Mother Courage and Her Children''). It is quite usual in Spanish, as you can see in other examples included in jachguate's answer, to use a variation of ''madre coraje'' for women who fight against some injustice, even if the character in Brecht's play does not really do that.

As far as I can see, "Mujeres coraje" is a term coined as the title of a documentary movie in 2012 in Perú that relates the life of two migrant women that lived in Lima, and since then the term was used to refer to other women in the press.
From my point of view, the term is a kind of poetic usage and Coraje here is a kind of title the author attaches to the women, but it is not not a regular expression of the language or a grammatically correct one.
I can think of other examples where you assign a title to a subject on the same way, that may make good names for an artwork, including books, movies, essays or press article titles, but you don't use it on a daily basis unless you're referring to that artworks, like:

Mujeres guerra (mujeres guerreras, mujeres que hacen la guerra, mujeres que provocan la guerra, etc.)
Hombres dinero (hombres que proveen dinero, hombres que son explotados por dinero, etc.)
Perros consuelo (perros que consuelan personas)

I could write a lot more that way.
I even found a series of books on Amazon, published in 2021, that uses the name: Mujeres Coraje, Historias de Amor propio

"You don't use it on a daily basis" Wow, I don't know about Perú but in Spain we use aposiciones all the time.

@jachguate Useful information. I will check the links you sent. It seems aposiciones are used in Spain at least according to another post.
